# When I read a message from Facebook through and IM app (Pidgin) and close the window, can it be marked as read on Facebook web as well?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I use Pidgin for chat on Facebook. Often when people write to me, I just read it and close the window that displayed their message (typically: me: by them:by -->[I close the window]). Now this leads to a red Facebook notification on the web about unread message - but I have read it.

Is there a way to achieve such behaviour (possibly with other clients)?

Or is it something that Facebook just does not permit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has it's own application, and at least for that one, it correctly tracks messages as being read or not. That application can be downloaded here: https://www.facebook.com/about/messenger

Comment: Well, so it seems to be possible. I will open a bug with Pidgin. I actually cannot use this application as I am on Ubuntu, but thanks for the answer!